# AWS EBS: If I use a volume of 15G, why does df report 8G?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I use a public snaphot.

I created one volume with 15G, and another with 25G, both from same snapshot. However, after mounting, df shows both at 8G and full. The lsblk shows the block devices with 15G and 25G. Do I need to give an extra argument when mounting?

How can I mount read/write?

```
lsblk  
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT  
..  
xvdf    202:80   0  25G  0 disk /data  
xvdg    202:96   0  15G  0 disk /data2  

df  
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on  
..
/dev/xvdf        8869442 8869442         0 100% /data  
/dev/xvdg        8869442 8869442         0 100% /data2  

mount  
..  
/dev/xvdf on /data type iso9660 (ro,relatime)  
/dev/xvdg on /data2 type iso9660 (ro,relatime)
```

Comment: Whay are you mounting them as iso9600?

Comment: Try to use `resize2fs` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your volume raw capacity is larger than your filesystem size, so, as @avihoo-mamca suggested, you need to extend your filesystem to the volume size, using `resize2fs`.